# Calculate Accurate Speed Using GPS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, gps, core-location

I am using following code to update location after every 0.1 second -

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CLController = [[CoreLocationController alloc] init];
    CLController.delegate = self;


// set auto update timer
    currentTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self
                                                  selector:@selector(updatestart) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

-(void)updatestart
{

        [CLController.locMgr startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

And then I am trying to calculate speed using

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation 
{
    [locMgr stopUpdatingLocation];

NSLog(@"%f",newLocation.speed);
}
```

I am getting speed in meter/sec but after some time the process slows down and even when I stop traveling the speed is being calculated.

**What I want is to get accurate speed and show alert if speed is above 12km/hr.**

Is there any other approach which I can use to find the same?

Thanks..

Comment: How can you know that you've stopped moving, or that you've started again, if you don't keep measuring? 0m/s is just as much a valid speed measurement as 12m/s is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting and stopping the location manager like that isn't the way to do it. You can't force it to give more location updates. Leave it running and average the location updates over time.  To get the best accuracy, use `kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation` for the location manager's `desiredAccuracy`.

Comment: If i don't forcefully start and stop update location then it shows me updated location only five times and stops after that.

Comment: It is working great now. But the problem i am facing is that it updates my speed after delay of 2-3 seconds. Also i want to mention that i am using GPS to fetch location. Is there anything i can do to make it perfect?

Comment: You could try using the `speed` property of `location`, but I'm not sure if it's going to be more accurate. You just have to wait for the GPS to get a fix before you can measure accurately.